# How to remove actual header location

Tags: php

I am trying to use header(location:) with definiton from config.php
Config.php :

```
/*LOCALHOST VERZE:*/ $Path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/docme"; //echo $Path;
    //$PathR = " ". $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/docme/";
    //$Path = "' ". $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/docme/";

    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Prague" );

    //Nastavení konstant webu
      define("dbserver", "127.0.0.1");
      define("dbuser", "root");
      define("dbpass", "mysql");
      define("dbname", "docme");
      define('site_title', 'DocMe!');
      define('path', $Path);
```

And here I am trying to use it in include and header(location)) but it's still redirecting me to `"localhost/docme/localhost/docme/....php"` and not into `"localhost/docme/....php"`

So is there any way how can I remove actual header location? Or ignore him and redirect directly to page I need? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$Path = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/docme";
```

To make the url absolute instead of relative